# How do I find formatting settings for CSV on Mac?

Tags: macos, csv, utf-8, tableau-api, export-to-csv

I have a Python program that extracts data from an API, applies transformations, and converts it to a csv to be used in Tableau. When I view the file in excel and Google Sheets, it looks fine. No data formatting or read errors as it is formatted in standard UTF8.

[image]

When I read it in Tableau, different story. You will notice how the columns lose shape and get parsed incorrectly.

I am thinking it has to do with the fact that my data set is text heavy and contains punctuation, but I have been able to work with data in this format just fine without having to do any custom formatting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your csv has multiline fields (which are quoted).

You'll somehow have to tell the Tableau reader/parser to read your data as quoted (and multiline).

Also check the escaping of the quotes (if they are inside a field) - usually this is done with another quote, but could also be with a backslash.